# How 2D Array_List Work?

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, 2d

I am a little confused on how a 2D array list work I read alot about this but I am still confused. I know that a 2D array list can be defined as follow:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayname=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

I imagine this arraylist as a two dimensional matrix lets say with four rows and five columns. then with 2D arraylist I should have four inner arraylist each has five columns. but how I can fill one inner matrix to five elements and then move to the next inner matrix.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This is a list of lists. Kinda like ragged array.

Comment: It's not a matrix, it's a `List` that contains `List`(s) of `Integer`(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have initialized empty lists, and put them into the 2d arraylist:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        arrayname.get(i).add(j);
    }
}
```

You can call `.get(index)` on your array, and you will get the inner array. Think of the out array as columns, and the inner array as the row in the column.

```
arrayname.get(1).get(2);
```

Would return the item in the second column, at the third row. The indexes look like: (the first number is what you put in the first `get()`, the second number is what you put in the second `get()`).

```
[0,0], [1,0], [2,0]
[0,1], [1,1], [2,1]
[0,2], [1,2], [2,2]
```

And so forth. So if you store the values

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

And you call

```
arrayname.get(0).get(2);
```

You would get the value 7

Comment: Immediate `NullPointerException`

Comment: This assumes the OP knows to instantiate his lists, it's not meant to be copy pasted into a main method and hit run.

Comment: Thank you that was very useful but when I type arrayname.get(1).get(2); the value of the element will be just [2] not [2,2]?

Comment: The value will be whatever is at that index. So for example, whatever is at the index 1,2

Comment: I think robert misunderstood your matrix at the end

Comment: The first get will get you an arraylist, that can be considered the rows. The second get gets whatever is in the row you choose.

Comment: Last question how I can get the size of the inner and the outer array lists? I know for one dmensional array it will be arrayname.size(); thanks in advance

Comment: For the outer, do `list.size();`, for the inners, do `list.get(index).size();` on each index.